# HTML links does not work when actual web page is open, only when I am testing it from Dreamweaver onto a browser

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, dreamweaver, mouseover

Well I have made image maps in Dreamweaver CS6 with HTML links attached to it. It works perfectly when I test it in any browser, but for some reason when I open my main hosted website to see if it works then it just refreshes the page onto a new tab. Also when I hover over the link it gives me a link URL at the bottom left corner basically stating "www.website.com/#". Here is the code on the image mapping:

```html
 <img src="images/Recom/magicians.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map2" border="0" />
              <map name="Map2" id="Map2">
                <area shape="rect" coords="7,6,158,184" href="2Smoothini.html" target="_blank" />
              </map>
```

The same thing happens when I try to access HTML from a word link. Example:

```html
<div align=center><a href="privacypolicy.htm"> Privacy Policy | <a href="#">Terms Of Use</a></div>
```

I am still developing a "Terms Of Use" page.

PS: I am hosting through Godaddy and Cpanel.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I edited in code tags and removed the ending, not because we are grumpy gits who don't like nice things (well, most of us aren't :) but because SO is trying to build a canonical archive of questions and answers and personal messages are discouraged, like they would be in, say, a Wikipedia article.

Comment: `when I open my main website to see if it works then it just refreshes the page onto a new tab.` can you clarify what that means? You mean, when you click on the image map?

Comment: An `href` value of `#` will behave as you've described. Which link are you trying to get to work, and what is it's value?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for the welcome kind sir :) Well when I click on the link from my actual hosted site it does not pick up the html page I linked in the code, it just opens a new tab with the index page all over again.

Comment: @Goose Hey and thanks for the feedback. I am trying to get the "2Smoothini.html" and the "privacypolicy.htm" to work, and not react as a "#" when I click on it from my actual hosted website.

Comment: does the `privacypolicy.htm` page exist? What happens if you go to `www.example.com/privacypolicy.htm`? Replace `www.example.com` with your site's domain

Comment: The privacy policy link doesn't have a closing tag, you just add another opening tag for the Terms of Use next to it - which has a # href value. If you add the closing `</a>` tag you should be able to use the Privacy Policy link (assuming the page does exist).

Comment: @Andrew It just pops back up to the top of the index page not opening anything different.

Comment: @Goose I have tried that and tried other html's in it's place too, still the same result. When I merely test it in the browsers it goes to the html pages without any hiccups at all, but from the hosted site it just replaces all the html links with a "#".

Comment: It shouldn't show links as '#' if it works locally on your computer. Something else is going on. What if you remove everything and just have `<a href="privacypolicy.htm"> Privacy Policy</a>` on your page. Also it sounds like that page doesn't exist. Did you upload `privacypolicy.htm` to your site?

Comment: @Andrew It is just strange that all the html links work when I test it in the browsers and not from the hosted site. All those html's are uploaded to Cpanel, my online file manager for my website. I am not sure if it is because I launched the site today and that it's new but I am sure those things should be effective on a freshly launched site.

Answer (score 0):

So guys after long hours of tutorials, googling, asking friends and eventually asking you good people, I have found the solution. It turns out that Cpanel has it's own html editor. Even though I code and link everything onto Dreamweaver it has decided that it is not good enough and felt neglected, thus forcing me to use it's HTML editor. I can link to all my relevant HTML pages easily now, thank you guys a ton upon a ton for spending time on me, you're awesome! **<3**